# Problems scraping figures from site

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I'm fairly used to scraping which is what is making this quite an annoying problem - I'm trying to scrape through VBA using the GET method but to get exchange rates of EUR to BHD that is offered by Revolut and have used the following code:

```
Sub My_Scraper()
Dim oXHTTP As Object
Dim doc As New HTMLDocument
Dim html As String
Dim url As String

url = "https://www.revolut.com/converter/EURBHD"

Set oXHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
oXHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
oXHTTP.send
html = oXHTTP.responseText
Set oXHTTP = Nothing
doc.body.innerHTML = html
Debug.Print doc.getElementsByClassName("rvl-Rate-rateLabel")(0).innerHTML                 ' Returns "Current rate" as expected
Debug.Print doc.getElementsByClassName("rvl-Rate-rateLabel")(0).NextSibling.innerHTML     ' Reurns "0" (not the rate quoted

End Sub
```

There are 2 sibling nodes which I have printed in the above code and when I looked a level up at the `innerHTML` of the `parentElement` it still isn't clear why this is happening (I have the correct piece of the HTML but the response is (at parent level - but not matching the developer tools console);

```
<DIV class=rvl-Rate-rateLabel data-reactid="1920">Current rate</DIV>
<DIV class=rvl-Rate-rateNumber data-reactid="1921">0</DIV>
```

Here's the developer tools console:
[image]

Comment: The converted value is generated dynamically so you can't get that using `xmlhttp`,`serverhttp` or `winhttp` requests because they can't deal with dynamic content. You should either choose IE or the url provided by Sam.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is common that sites rebuild the DOM while loading, and I suppose that is why you get your problem. I can suggest as slightly different approach instead.
If you examine the requests in your browser, you will find this:

```
https://www.revolut.com/api/quote/internal?symbol=EURBHD ...
```

Remove everything after EURBHD and you'll something far easier to parse.

Answer (score 2):

And this is how the total script should look like to get the converted value:

```
Sub GetVal()
    Dim res As Variant

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.revolut.com/api/quote/internal?symbol=EURBHD", False
        .send
        res = .responseText
    End With

    res = Split(Split(res, "rate"":")(1), ",")(0)
    MsgBox res
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks - I'd parsed it with a convoluted `Mid()` function - the split solution is much cleaner!